# Inserting a period mark into an array at specific points

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I want to allow a user to look up a word using the Dinosaurus gem. I have that part figured out and I have it so the user inputs the number of sentences and paragraphs they want. This is displayed using a post process. However, I want to be able to separate each individual sentence using a period (`"."`), but I don't know where and how I would write that underneath my post process.

This is the code from my HTML file, with a `<form>` tag. Within the form I designated the variables `@nsentences` and `@nparagraphs` to be the number of sentences per paragraph and number of paragraphs entered by the user.

```
<form action = "/process" method="post">
    Topic: <input type="text" name ="word"></br>
    Number of Sentences <input type="text" name="nsentences"></br>
    Number of Paragraphs <input type="text" name="nparagraphs"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is the post process in my app.rb file, which links to my HTML file from above. In the app.rb file:

```
post '/process' do
  @topic = params['word']
  @nsentences = params['nsentences']
  @nparagraph = params['nparagraphs']

  results = []
  results = Dinosaurus.lookup(@topic)

  results2 = []
  results2 = Dinosaurus.lookup(results['noun']['syn'].sample)

  y = @nsentences.to_i
  z = @nparagraph.to_i

  @nwords = []
  @sentences = []
  @content = []

  results['noun']['syn'].each do |word|
    @nwords << word
  end

  results2['noun']['syn'].each do |word|
    @nwords << word
  end

  y.times do
    a_sentence = []

    15.times do
      a_sentence << @nwords.sample
    end
```

This is where I push the sentence within the array, `@sentences`, which is a blank array that will contain `y` number of sentences that the user wants.

```
    @sentences << a_sentence #.join('. ') #.to_s + "."

  end

  z.times do
    @content << @sentences #.join('. ') #clean #.join(' ') #clean
  end

  @contentclean = @content.join(' ')

  erb :some_file

end
```

Within my ERB file I have made it so it displays the `@contentclean`.

Comment: We need to see sample input data, and an example of the output.

Comment: You don't need to tell us whether you're new to programming. Just do your research, and ask a good question showing us what you tried, and give us the input data we need, along with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use:

```
y.times do
  ...
end
```

Instead, add the sentences into the collection (using `map`) and `join` using ". ":

```
(1..y).map{(1..15).map{@nwords.sample}.join}.join(". ")
```